# Angular2, relative navigation (two levels back ../../)

Tags: angular, routes, navigation

I have a back button in my application, which navigates relatively some levels back. In case of one level

```
this.router.navigate(['..'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

it works perfectly (resulted route url:`http://localhost:3000/three/two/one`). In case of two level back rel. navigation

```
this.router.navigate(['..', '..'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

router navigates two levels back, **BUT** the resulted route url looks now like `http://localhost:3000/three/two/`(tailing slash, which is not correct).

Am I doing something wrong or could it be a bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case of two levels down use this:

```
this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you. But do you know why its the case? In case of this.router.navigate we give an array of segments. In your working solution we have an array with one entry, but this entry is semantically two segments.

Comment: I think your original essentially becomes `[ '../..']` but the concept of 'going up a level' requires `../` therefore it goes up one level and then tries to look for `..` and doesn't treat it as anything special (in fact I was getting `..` as a server side parameter!). In fact `['../', '../']` also works :-)

Comment: [routerLink]="['../../']" works as wll in Angular 10/11

Answer (score 0):

Use the Location.back() method instead, Location.back() method takes you to the last page in your browsers history.

in your component:

```
import { Location }  from '@angular/common';
//some othe code ......
//in your class
constructor(private location: Location) {}

//create a method to go back
goBack() {
  this.location.back();
}
```

Now create a back button in your component.html and bind this method to it:

```
<button (click)="goBack()" > Back </button>
```

Comment: In my case does Location.back() not fulfill my reqs. But nevertheless thank you.