# Navigation from one component to another keeps parameters on Url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my application I have employee-details component and url looks like `http://localhost:4200/employee/123`
From here when I click button to go back I used

```
this.router.navigate(['/'], { queryParams: { message: this.message }, relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, skipLocationChange: true });
```

It works perfectly and page navigates to required component(employee-list). But it keep employee id 123 on url which actually should not be and should look like `http://localhost:4200/employee/`. How can I do it correctly.

Comment: I would think that using the relativeTo apporach in combination with '/' might be the problem here. Using relative navigation have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994297/angular2-relative-navigation-two-levels-back, otherwise using absolute routing a navigate to ['/employee] should work too.

Comment: And your skipLocationChange, I haven't used that before but the documentation says it will navigate silently, don't know if that means, that your route doesn't change but you will be navigated. Have you tried navigating without skipLocationChange?

Answer (score 0):

You can give 
`this.router.navigate(['../'], {queryParams:'' relativeTo: this.route });`
or 
`this.router.navigate(['employee'], {queryParams: '' });`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in question but I have to pass some parameters to required component. So can not remove queryParams.

Comment: the queryParams shouldn't be the problem, since the employee id is a param within the route not a queryParam. But using relativeRouting, using just '/' would do nothing. You have to use somthing like this this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route }); Please see the link in the comment under your question. A similar question was asked and answered before.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig exactly. Updated my answer.

Comment: Have you tried using ['../'] instead of ['/'] as the first parameter for the navigate call ?

Comment: yes I tried with ['../'] also but the result was same i.e. navigated successfully but url does not change

Comment: Can you post your route configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the skipLocationChange. The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) states the following:

> skipLocationChanges: Navigates without pushing a new state into history.

This is exactly what you are experiencing I think: the navigation works but your route is not changing. Please remove the skipLocationChange.

Seeing this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109731/angular-4-routing-redirectto-with-skiplocationchange): The solution was to use skipLocationChanges to navigate to localhost/canvas without displaying 'canvas' in the url. You want the exact opposite. So I think using skipLocationChanges: true is the thing you don't want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my problem from following link
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

It helps transferring data between pages using services
a) Parent to child
b) Child to parent
c) Sibling to parent